# "This bundle is invalid" with MonoTouch and SDK 4.3

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, app-store-connect

I'm running into a problem submitting my application through the Application Loader. I'm receiving the message "This bundle is invalid. Apple is not currently accepting applications built with this version of the SDK."

I've installed Xcode 4.0.1 w/SDK 4.3 ("4A1006", March 24), and I've reinstalled both MonoDevelop and MonoTouch. I've also made sure my build/bundle settings are using SDK 4.3, and I've tried each of the min versions of 4.0, 4.1, 4.2, and 4.3.

Suggestions?

Update: I've uninstalled Xcode 4 (rebooted), installed latest Xcode 3 same w/SDK (rebooted), and reinstalled MonoDevelop & MonoTouch. Still no luck unfortunately. I tried with and without manually specifying DTXcode:0400.

I've been reinstalling MonoTouch by re-running the installer. Is there a way to do a clean uninstall of MT and could that help in this case?

Comment: FWIW, I'm using SDK 4.3 with XCode 3.2.6 (which you can still get from connect.apple.com; go to "Developer Tools" under "Downloads"), minimum OS version 4.1, and I'm having no trouble. Haven't tried XCode 4 at all yet. What versions of MD and MT are you using?

Comment: Okay, that's what I've got, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple changed the keys required in the application manifest in iOS SDK 4.3.1. We've released a new MonoDevelop build to track this.

Comment: Thank you (and Geoff) for fast responses.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 4.0.1 was released last week with the iOS 4.3.1 SDK, you need to install that.

Comment: Thx for the reply. I'm actually on that version I believe. I'm on the March 24 release, but I don't see "4.3.1" in the name just "4.3".

Comment: Please upload your Info.plist for me to see.

Comment: Looks like a fresh project creates a slightly different plist. I'm going to try using the newer plist format...

Comment: Not that Info.plist, the one from the .app you're trying to upload to apple.  MonoDevelop merges in more keys at build time.

Comment: No luck on Xcode3 either. OP updated. Latest plist here: http://dev3.plainjoe.net/Info.plist%20(3).zip

Answer (score 0):

One thought: Double-check that you're building/signing for release, and not e.g. for ad-hoc distribution.

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem for one week and i just solve it today , it seems that SDK 4.3 has a problem with the monotouch anyway
the one works with me i uninstall the SDK and install SDK 4.2 with Xcode 3.2.5 and Remove monorouch 3.2.6 and install 3.2.3 . and it will work.